# Big O of duplicate check function

Tags: c

I would like to know exactly how to compute the big O of the second while when the number of repetitions keeps going down over time.

```
int duplicate_check(int a[], int n) 
     {
      int i = n; 
       while (i > 0) 
       {
          i--; 
          int j = i - 1; 
         while (j >= 0) 
          { 
            if (a[i] == a[j]) 
               { 
                 return 1; 

               } 

           j--; 
          } 
        }
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Still `O(n^2)` regardless of the smaller repetition.

The value you are computing is `Sum of (n-k) for k = 0 to n.`

This equates to `(n^2 + n) / 2` which since `O()` ignores constants and minor terms is `O(n^2)`.

Note you can solve this problem more efficiently by sorting the array `O(nlogn)` and then searching for two consecutive numbers that are the same `O(n)` so total `O(nlogn)`

Comment: So would it be right to say that if at some point the inner loop runs the equivalent to O (n) even if after that it runs n-1,...,n-3,.... n-k the inner loop would still be O(n^2) assuming the outer loop runs O(n)? Like what really matters is the time the loop runs the most in the worst case scenario?

Comment: Agree: "can solve this problem more efficiently by sorting the array `O(nlogn)`"  Yet can this even be better? Hmmm.  Sounds akin to the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

Comment: @VanderIg yes Big O is a worst case scenario measurement. @Chux There maybe be other approaches that are better than `O(nlogn)` but I didn't know any off hand. Also I think the birthday paradox only works because of the finite number of options (366).

Answer (score 1):

Big O is an estimate/theoretical speed, it's not the exact calculation.

Like twain249 said, regardless, the time complexity is `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

BigO shows the worst case time complexity of an algorithm that means the maximum time an algorithm can take ever.It shows upper bound which indicates that whatever the input is time complexity will always be under that bound.
In your case the worst case will when i will iterate until 0 then complexity will be like:

for i=n j will run n-1 times for i=n-1 j will run n-2 times and so on.
adding all (n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+............(n-n)=(n-1)*(n)/2=n^2/2-n/2
after ignoring lower term that is n and constant that is 1/2 it becomes n^2.
So O(n^2) that's how it is computed.